# How to call api between two project in local?

Tags: docker, symfony

I clone 2 project to local machine.

- The first project is symfony 5.3 and required php 8. It's available docker-compose.yml file. I'm a newbie docker, so I follow README.md to run docker. Project works well on server : http://localhost:80/.
- The second project is syfony 4.3 and required php 7.3. There is not docker file. I just install symfony server and run `symfony server:start`. Project woks well on server: https://127.0.0.1:8000/.

Now in first project, I would like to use http client to call public api of the second project like : `$httpClient->request('GET', 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/foo');`. But it error : **Couldn't connect to server for https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/foo**.
I guess the first project run in a "individual" environment which set up by docker. And the second project run in a "real" environment which set up by my local machine. So that the reason they cannot realize each other. How could I do in this case ?

Comment: I would recommend to expose port 8000 from the docker and try again.

Comment: Try doing the request to `host.docker.internal:8000`. That should map to your host machine.

Comment: If you run both in the same docker compose you can use the service names and DNS records and make an http request to `http://service2/api/foo` for example

Comment: dou you have a self signed cert for localhost? if not maybe https is problem

Answer (score 0):

that looks like the docker doesn't publish port 80 from inside to outside, but I can't be sure without seeing the docker file and the execute command. so if you can share that, it will be awesome.